# Pros and cons of Oracle ADF framework and comparison with other frameworks

Tags: performance, cross-browser, web-frameworks, oracle-adf

Let's discuss pros and cons of Oracle ADF framework. Please, share your experience and knowledege about using Oracle ADF (comparison to other frameworks like Java Server Faces, Google Web Toolkit, Django, Ruby on Rails and ASP.NET MVC Framework is preferable)

Main criteria are: efficiency, support (community support), browser compatability (does it work on all browsers? including Mobile), additional libraries and some other factors.

Answer (score 3):

For browser support look here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/jdev11gr2-cert-405181.html#Browsers

Note that there is also the new ADF Mobile - which allows you to build on-device apps (not browser based).

For community look here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/community/index.html

One key difference against many of the other frameworks you mentioned is the level of tooling support - with JDeveloper you can get a lot done with minimal coding, and then add code where needed.
Another aspect is the completeness of the framework - so not just a UI, or controller, or DB access but all of those and much more.

Probably worth mentioning that you also have a free version of Oracle ADF called Oracle ADF Essentials.

Comment: Hello Shay! Thanks for you answer. I have the following situation: given I have Oracle BI publisher and Oracle Spatial. Can I use "Oracle iframes" in ADF to integrate BI publisher, spatial with my custom ADF app. The idea is to have a common header in my app with different content like adf forms, bi publisher, some other oracle products.

Could you also please have a look at the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13859634/how-to-enclose-oracle-bi-publisher-into-iframe-of-some-other-app

Answer (score 0):

I would be careful in deciding to use Oracle ADF due to its reliance on JSR 227. JSR 227 is an extremely complex specification with no in-depth information available. I have written about this [here](http://henrietteharmse.wordpress.com/2012/12/19/why-i-have-no-confidence-in-oracle-adf/).

Answer (score -1):

You might find this link helpful: 
https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=9450798

Also, ADF is an end-to-end framework, so there is less fiddling with having to get bits working together. Also, contrary to popular belief, ADF is not restricted to Oracle development only, although it does excel here. Also, there is support for ADF development of ADF Faces and ADF Model in Eclipse.
Not sure what you mean by "other libraries and factors."