# How to enclose Oracle BI Publisher into iframe of some other app?

Tags: iframe, oracle11g, bi-publisher

How to enclose Oracle BI Publisher into iframe of some other app?

I have installed Oracle BI Publisher 11g (Trial version) and would like to enclose it into iframe of some other app. It works with other websites/apps but does not work with the Publisher. Instead of showing it in the iframe it automatically redirects to the url of the Publisher.

I tried to google a solution for this problem amd found the following post: http://atlantabi.blogspot.com/2011/12/obiee-11g-obiee-content-cannot-be.html
But I can't find the instanceconfig.xml where I need to add the following entry

```
<InIFrameRenderingMode>allow</InIFrameRenderingMode>
```

What might be the reason? (May be it is click jacking prevention?)

How to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

are you trying to enclose the entire BI Publisher app into an iframe, complete with the layout editor, the data model editor, etc.? If so you likely won't be able to - BI Publisher is a pretty complicated web app that uses a lot of Javascript.

The *Atlanta BI* article you've linked explains how to enclose the *HTML output of a Report* in an iframe.